# Duality between topological order and SPT in $K$-matrix formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topological-order, duality

It is a well-known fact that the low energy effective theory of intrinsic topological order is multi-components Chern-Simons theory $\frac{K_{I J}}{4 \pi} \int_{\mathcal{M}} d t d^{2} x \epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho} a_{I, \mu} \partial_{\nu} a_{J, \rho}$, meanwhile one can use unimodular symmetry K matrix to describe SPT state. Another fact is that when gauging the symmetric group G of SPT, one has iTO or gapless state. My question is that is there exist some kinds of "gauge duality" between K matrix of iTO and SPT? For example any possible duality between Z_2 topological order and bosonic integer quantum hall?